temperature effect on 2.4 dichloroquinazoline
In 2,4 dichloroquinazoline, the first animation step requires ice bath conditions, while the second one requires high temperature condions so why, is the first one exothermic , but why the second not although both requires bond breaking and formation

You should have given the details of this procedure (I assume synthesis of the given compound) if you want someone to answer your question.
